# Removing objects from array not clearing memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

I have an `NSMutableArray` of `MyDayObject` objects in my app...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *days;
```

I also keep a link to the "current" day...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyDayObject *day;
```

The code for `MyDayObject` is...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyDayObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *notes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;

@end
```

There is no implementation code to it.

I am simulating a low memory warning and running this code...

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    [self.days removeAllObjects];

    [self.days addObject:self.currentDay];
}
```

I can see the memory going up when I add new days into the `days` mutable array.

When I simulate the low memory warning I can see that my function is being called.

But when I run it the memory usage isn't going down at all.

It remains at the same level it got to when I was adding stuff into it.

Any ideas how I can clear out this memory?

**NOTE**

I deleted my previous question which was similar but based around linked lists. I changed the usage to an `NSArray` instead but I'm getting this behaviour now.

Comment: Check if your `MyDayObject` instances receive `dealloc` message. Put a breakpoint or `NSLog` inside its `dealloc` method.

Comment: OK, did that. They are definitely being deallocated. I wonder if I just need to wait for it to clear the memory after removing the objects? Weird?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that. All we can do as developers is to make sure we release our objects. You can try to send the memory warning twice or try to send a real memory warning (not simulated).

Comment: OK, thanks. Will keep an eye out but leave it for now.

Comment: What about the scale?, I mean maybe MyDayObject it' s so small that you wouldn't see any difference into the allocation graphics. Maybe there are bigger order objects. Howeever you can make allocation count retain counts and check if object are released and deallocated. Try to set a base line heapshot and check for differences.